# BroadcastReceiver doesn't work?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

My Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastRecieverInternet">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Its my  Service code block.

```
public class MyBroadCastRecieverInternet extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyLog","Internet Reciever is on");
    }

}
```

Is there any mistake? I didn't find anything. It doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: what do you wanna do?

Comment: What targetSdk do you use?

Comment: Your implementation actually works. I copied your code inside a sample app and whenerver I switch mobile on the emulator on or off the log message from the service appears.

Comment: targetSdkVersion 26 bro @smakova
I want to learn internet connection type when type of internet changed.

Comment: @migos its doesn't work on me . Can you send me your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html):

> Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive
> CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare their broadcast
> receiver in the manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
> broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with
> Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.
>
> CONNECTIVITY_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

You can downgrade your `targetSdk` to 23 or use dynamic broadcast receiver like this:

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isConnected = ConnectionManager.isConnectedToInternet(context);

        if (!isConnected) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext = this;

    private ConnectivityReceiver mConnectivityReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mConnectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver);

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: app is receiving CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, not CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: @user1506104 JFYI: `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: you should add it in your answer for clarity

Comment: How can i write a dynamic reciever ?is  there any documentation?

Comment: When my app closed. This service going to stop right ?

Comment: @KimJoyJoy What service?

Comment: Broadcastreciever. I want to use it with backgroud like beheivor Android SDK of 23.

Comment: @KimJoyJoy Show your exception from logcat when your app was closed

Comment: No its doesn't work when the app closed. so when my app going to force closed , my broadcast service closing too. I want to run it all time.

Comment: @KimJoyJoy When you should downgrade your targetSdk, because Android now tries to get rid of background overhead

Comment: But my service don't work on Android 7. I need to use it newest version of android too..

Comment: @shmakova What If I don't want to unregister my Broadcastreciever ? Cause I am using PACKAGE_ADDED and PACKAGE_REMOVED.Is there any workaround without target to 25 .

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach. You don't need to make a whole new class for your broadcast receiver but you can use it inside your Main Activity like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiveLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Your custom action
    }

};

IntentFilter receiveLocationFilter = new IntentFilter();
receiveLocationFilter.addAction("android.intent.RECEIVE_LOCATION");
```

Register the receiver in `onStart`:

```
registerReceiver(receiveLocationReceiver, receiveLocationFilter);
```

Unregister it in `onStop`:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiveLocationReceiver);
```

Then when you need to send the broadcast all you need is :

```
Intent sendBroadcastIntent = new Intent("android.intent.RECEIVE_LOCATION");
sendBroadcast(sendBroadcastIntent);
```